# Reduce video size on Android

Tags: gratis, android, open-source, video, video-editing

I need to reduce the size of an Android screencast, on Android.

The screencast is a few seconds long MP4, takes ~50 MB, and I want to reduce it to about 10 MB.

Context: I want to post a screencast to a service (GitHub) which says `Video is too large to be added`

Gratis, ideally open source.

Comment: Guess you already expected my "standard hint" to one of my app listings? OK, I don't want to disappoint you: [Video Editing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video). For FOSS: maybe [Video Transcoder](https://f-droid.org/packages/protect.videoeditor/) (last updated 2019)? Not many alternatives – especially if you want some without a mass of trackers inside.

Comment: @Izzy Video Transcoder is not available for Android 13, it seems.

Comment: Oh. So no FOSS alternatives anymore? Sad.